# Should I use new classes or create partials?

Tags: c#, oop

The situation: I have a class that generates XML and the content of the XML is very large. Right now I have a function for each node, but I notice that the class is becoming very big. I want to prevent this so I was thinking of creating a new class for every node. A collegua of mine had different thoughts and he suggested to create partial classes.

What would you suggest and why?

Relevant code:

```
public class IbTaxReturnTagCreator : TagCreatorBase
{
    private readonly IMathLibQueryClient mathLibQueryClient;
    private readonly IUserIdentity userIdentity;

    public IbTaxReturnTagCreator(ILynxDataUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
        IMathLibQueryClient mathLibQueryClient,
        IUserIdentity userIdentity)
        : base(unitOfWork)
    {
        this.mathLibQueryClient = mathLibQueryClient;
        this.userIdentity = userIdentity;
    }

    protected override void WriteTag(Domain.TaxReturn taxReturn)
    {
        WriteStartingIbTag(taxReturn);

        WriteEmployeeTag(taxReturn);

        WriteRelationTag(taxReturn);

        WriteFeatures(taxReturn);

        WriteClosingIbTag();
    }

    private void WriteStartingIbTag(Domain.TaxReturn taxReturn)
    {
        XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("ib");
        WriteIbAttributes(taxReturn);
    }

    private void WriteIbAttributes(Domain.TaxReturn taxReturn)
    {
        // Write attributes in ib tag
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("txrid", taxReturn.Id.ToString());
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("guid", taxReturn.Guid.ToString());
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("sofinr", taxReturn.FiscalNumber);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("belastingjaar", taxReturn.TaxYear.ToString());
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("valuta", taxReturn.Currency);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("lastformview", taxReturn.LastFormOpen);
        if (taxReturn.InspectionOffice == null)
        {
            XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("inspectie", string.Empty);
        }
        else
        {
            XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("inspectie", taxReturn.InspectionOffice.Code);
        }
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("beconnr", taxReturn.BeconNumber);
        if (taxReturn.TaxReturnPartner == null)
        {
            XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("partnerguid", string.Empty);
        }
        else
        {
            XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("partnerguid", taxReturn.TaxReturnPartner.Guid.ToString());
        }
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("partnersofinr", "3.0");
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("biljetsoort", "3.0");
    }

    private void WriteEmployeeTag(Domain.TaxReturn taxReturn)
    {
        XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("medewerker");
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("code", taxReturn.Employee.Name);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("indienst", ToUSDateFormat(taxReturn.Employee.EmployedDateTime));
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("uitdienst", ToUSDateFormat(taxReturn.Employee.DischargeDateTime));

        XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("relatie");
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("sofinr", taxReturn.Employee.Customer.FiscalNumber);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("zoeknaam", taxReturn.Employee.Customer.SearchName);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("type", taxReturn.Employee.Customer.CustomerType);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("voorletters", taxReturn.Employee.Customer.Initials);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("tussenvoegsels", taxReturn.Employee.Customer.PrefixLastName);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("achternaam", taxReturn.Employee.Customer.LastName);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("geslacht", taxReturn.Employee.Customer.Gender.Id.ToString());
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("gebdatum", ToUSDateFormat(taxReturn.Employee.Customer.BirthDateTime));
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("ovldatum", ToUSDateFormat(taxReturn.Employee.Customer.DeceasedDateTime));

        XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("postadres");
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("straat", taxReturn.Employee.Customer.PaStreet);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("straat2", taxReturn.Employee.Customer.PaStreet2);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("huisnr", taxReturn.Employee.Customer.PaHouseNumber);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("huisnrtoe", taxReturn.Employee.Customer.PaHouseNumberPostfix);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("postcode", taxReturn.Employee.Customer.PaZipCode);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("plaats", GetCity(taxReturn.Employee.Customer.PaCity));
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("landcode", GetCountry(taxReturn.Employee.Customer.PaCountry));
        XmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

        XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("woonadres");
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("WAstraat", taxReturn.Employee.Customer.HaStreet);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("WAstraat2", taxReturn.Employee.Customer.HaStreet2);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("WAhuisnr", taxReturn.Employee.Customer.HaHouseNumber);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("WAhuisnrtoe", taxReturn.Employee.Customer.HaHouseNumberPostfix);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("WApostcode", taxReturn.Employee.Customer.HaZipCode);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("plaats", GetCity(taxReturn.Employee.Customer.HaCity));
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("landcode", GetCountry(taxReturn.Employee.Customer.HaCountry));
        XmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

        XmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // End relation tag
        XmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // End employee tag
    }

    private void WriteRelationTag(Domain.TaxReturn taxReturn)
    {
        XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("relatie");

        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("sofinr", taxReturn.Customer.FiscalNumber);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("zoeknaam", taxReturn.Customer.SearchName);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("type", taxReturn.Customer.CustomerType);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("voorletters", taxReturn.Customer.Initials);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("tussenvoegsels", taxReturn.Customer.PrefixLastName);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("achternaam", taxReturn.Customer.LastName);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("geslacht", taxReturn.Customer.Gender.Id.ToString());
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("gebdatum", ToUSDateFormat(taxReturn.Customer.BirthDateTime));
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("ovldatum", ToUSDateFormat(taxReturn.Customer.DeceasedDateTime));

        XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("postadres");
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("straat", taxReturn.Customer.PaStreet);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("straat2", taxReturn.Customer.PaStreet2);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("huisnr", taxReturn.Customer.PaHouseNumber);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("huisnrtoe", taxReturn.Customer.PaHouseNumberPostfix);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("postcode", taxReturn.Customer.PaZipCode);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("plaats", GetCity(taxReturn.Customer.PaCity));
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("landcode", GetCountry(taxReturn.Customer.PaCountry));
        XmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

        XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("woonadres");
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("WAstraat", taxReturn.Customer.HaStreet);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("WAstraat2", taxReturn.Customer.HaStreet2);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("WAhuisnr", taxReturn.Customer.HaHouseNumber);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("WAhuisnrtoe", taxReturn.Customer.HaHouseNumberPostfix);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("WApostcode", taxReturn.Customer.HaZipCode);
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("plaats", GetCity(taxReturn.Customer.HaCity));
        XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("landcode", GetCountry(taxReturn.Customer.HaCountry));
        XmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

        XmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // End relation tag
    }

    private void WriteFeatures(Domain.TaxReturn taxReturn)
    {
        XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("features");

        var featureValues = GetFeatureValues(taxReturn);
        foreach (var feature in featureValues)
        {
            XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("feature");

            XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("id", feature.Name);
            XmlWriter.WriteCData(feature.Value);

            XmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // Closing tag feature
        }

        var featureTables = GetFeatureTableValues(taxReturn).GroupBy(f => f.FeatureName);
        foreach (var feature in featureTables)
        {
            XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("table");
            XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("id", feature.Key);

            var rows = feature.OrderBy(f => f.RowId).Select(f => f.RowId).Distinct();
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("row");

                foreach (var subfeature in feature.Where(f => f.RowId == row))
                {
                    XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("subfeature");
                    XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("id", subfeature.Name);
                    XmlWriter.WriteCData(subfeature.Value);
                    XmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                }

                XmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // Closing row tag
            }

            XmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // Closing table feature
        }

        var featuresIafWoInvestment = GetIafSubFeaturesWithoutInvestment(taxReturn).GroupBy(f => f.FeatureName);
        foreach (var feature in featuresIafWoInvestment)
        {
            XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("table");
            XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("id", feature.Key);

            var rows = feature.OrderBy(f => f.Row).Select(f => f.Row).Distinct();
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("row");

                foreach (var subfeature in feature.Where(f => f.Row == row))
                {
                    XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("subfeature");
                    XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("id", subfeature.SubFeatureName);
                    XmlWriter.WriteCData(subfeature.SubFeatureValue);
                    XmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                }

                XmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // Closing row tag
            }

            XmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // Closing table feature
        }

        var featuresIafWithInvestments = GetIafSubFeaturesWithInvestment(taxReturn).GroupBy(f => f.FeatureName);
        foreach (var feature in featuresIafWithInvestments)
        {
            XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("table");
            XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("id", feature.Key);
            XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("iafguid", feature.First().InvestmentGuid.Value.ToString());
            XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("iafzoeknaam", feature.First().InvestmentName);

            var rows = feature.OrderBy(f => f.Row).Select(f => f.Row).Distinct();
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("row");

                foreach (var subfeature in feature.Where(f => f.Row == row))
                {
                    XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("subfeature");
                    XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("id", subfeature.SubFeatureName);
                    XmlWriter.WriteCData(subfeature.SubFeatureValue);
                    XmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                }

                XmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // Closing row tag
            }

            XmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // Closing table features
        }

        XmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // Closing features features
    }

    private void WriteClosingIbTag()
    {
        XmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
    }

    private string GetCountry(Domain.Country country)
    {
        var countryString = string.Empty;

        if (country != null)
            countryString = country.Code;

        return countryString;
    }

    private string GetCity(Domain.City city)
    {
        var cityString = string.Empty;

        if (city != null)
            cityString = city.Name;

        return cityString;
    }

    private FeatureNameValueView[] GetFeatureValues(Domain.TaxReturn taxReturn)
    {
        var featureValues = this.mathLibQueryClient.GetAllFeatureValues(this.userIdentity.UserId, taxReturn.Id);
        return featureValues;
    }

    private SubFeatureDetailView[] GetFeatureTableValues(Domain.TaxReturn taxReturn)
    {
        var featureNames = this.mathLibQueryClient.GetAllSubFeatureValues(this.userIdentity.UserId, taxReturn.Id);
        return featureNames;
    }

    private SubFeatureInvestmentDetailView[] GetIafSubFeaturesWithoutInvestment(Domain.TaxReturn taxReturn)
    {
        var featureNames = this.mathLibQueryClient.GetInvestmentSubFeatures(this.userIdentity.UserId, taxReturn.Id, false);
        return featureNames;
    }

    private SubFeatureInvestmentDetailView[] GetIafSubFeaturesWithInvestment(Domain.TaxReturn taxReturn)
    {
        var featureNames = this.mathLibQueryClient.GetInvestmentSubFeatures(this.userIdentity.UserId, taxReturn.Id, true);
        return featureNames;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually every node within your document is an object that has attributes. Thus you may implement a class for every nested object-type. This way you could also use simple XML-serialization techniques rather then writing all the stuff self.

Comment: I've deliberately chosen to use XmlSerialization because this is the fastest way of creating xml files. It is no exception that the XML is > 1MB.

Comment: +1 For looking into XML-serialization rather than doing it all manually. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx and the Purchase Order Example.

Comment: @Martijn Is speed an actual problem for you, or have you just read somewhere that XmlWriter may be a bit faster in some circumstances and chose it based on that? XML > 1MB is not that much and I don't think using the XML Serializer is much slower. I would do this the clean way first with proper marked up objects and the XML Serializer. Then later if it turns out to be a huge issue with performance, look into optimizing it.

Comment: " this is the fastest way of creating xml files" have you verified this or is it a guess?

Answer (score 0):

Using partial classes just because the class is getting big would be a hack. Partial classes are out there to enable the use of tools to individually create parts of the class for you. I think at the moment your class has a manageable size and you are the only entity writing it.

If you want to think of this in an object oriented manner, any class should be able to serialize itself and should have an interface declaring that. You can also extend this later on if you have other ways of representing them. Instead of you having to change one main class each time the representation of any of the nodes change, you can change that specific node's class(Employee, Relation, etc). This would help your source control and versioning.

Comment: Thanx, but this is just the start of class. The size of this class will be trippled at least. But I think I agree about the partials part.